# BackgroundAudioPlayer does not exist in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal Apps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

This Code Working in WP8.0 but when coming to WP8.1 BackgroundAudioPlayer is not working

```
 if (BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState == PlayState.Playing)
 {
     if (BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance != null &&
         BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track.Source.ToString().Contains("Claps.mp3"))
     {
         BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Stop();
     }
 }
```

Comment: When you say 'not working' do you mean it's failing to compile, or failing at runtime, either loading due to missing dependencies or just not playing the audio? MSDN says it [is supported in 8.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.backgroundaudioplayer(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: Yes its Working in WP8.1 Silver Light but Not Working in WP8.1 Runtime apps

Comment: For *WP8.1 RunTIme* apps, please refer to [Background audio (Windows Phone Store apps)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642090.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight code is not working in Windows Phone 8.1 XAML because the API is different, there is no BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance, there is  BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current and more differences, take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642090.aspx

Comment: i Have not found any property regarding geting the source track, if you find any property regarding track source please infom me.